# Getting the time between page load and page refresh -- I have negative time?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, time

I'm trying to make a "game" of sorts on my local browser. The idea is to present a number or word to the player, and then the player will enter the associated word (if what is presented is a number) or number (if what is presented is a word). I've done that easily enough, and I'm using a database to access these words.

Now what I'd like to do is measure the time the player takes to enter the answer for each question (not for each game -- I could just sum all the question times to get that), then insert the values into the database.

I've got a script running, but the measured time is showing me a negative value. Here's the script (explanation at the bottom)

```
<?php

try{
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=databasename', 'username', 'password');
    $form_uuid = uniqid();
    $_SESSION['Qtime'][$form_uuid] = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

##########################################################
##################### GAME MODULE ########################

    #error_reporting(0);

    $id = mt_rand(0,99);
    $rev = mt_rand(0,5); //reverse, so 0 asks for id and 1 asks for peg

    $random = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM major WHERE id='.$id);

    if($rev < 3){
        $question = $random->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['peg'];
    } else {
        $question = $random->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['id'];
    }

    #echo '<pre>', print_r($handler->query('SELECT * FROM major WHERE id='.$id)->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)), '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST), '</pre>';
    #echo $rev;

    echo '<h1>';
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        echo 'Next: ';
    }
    echo $question, '</h1>';

    $P_rev = $_POST['rev'];
    if($P_rev < 3){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM major WHERE id='".$_POST['guess']."' AND peg='".$_POST['Q']."'";
    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM major WHERE id='".$_POST['Q']."' AND peg='".$_POST['guess']."'";
    }

    #echo $sql;
    $check = $handler->query($sql)->fetch();
    if($check){
        echo '<h2>Correct!</h2>';
    } else {
        if(!empty($_POST)){
            echo '<h2>Wrong</h2>';
        }
    }

?>

<form action="flashcards.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="guess" id="guess" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Q" value="<?php echo $question; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="rev" value="<?php echo $rev; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="<?php print $form_uuid; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="end_time" value="<?php echo round(microtime(true) * 1000) ?>">
</form>


<?php

    #echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST), '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>', print_r($_SESSION), '</pre>';

    #echo $form_uuid, '<br/>';
    $form_uuid = $_POST['form_id'];
    #echo $form_uuid;

    #echo '<pre>', print_r($_SESSION), '</pre>';


    $key = key($_SESSION['Qtime']);
    $start_time = $_SESSION['Qtime'][$key];
        // Do other form processing here..

    $end_time = $_POST['end_time'];

    echo $end_time - $start_time;

?>
```

I've got a lot of echos in there for debugging purposes. Anyway:

### Getting the start time

What I did was get the session time using

`$form_uuid = uniqid();
$_SESSION['Qtime'][$form_uuid] = round(microtime(true) * 1000);`

The unique id allows me to differentiate between this question and the previous question. So then, this should give me the time at the beginning of the page refresh.

### Getting the end time

So far so good. But the issue comes when I try to record the end time. I record it by putting this in my form:

`<input type="hidden" name="end_time" value="<?php echo round(microtime(true) * 1000) ?>">`

My impression is that this is supposed to give me the time when the form is submitted, right? Which means it measures the page submit time. But when I get the difference:

### Subtracting to get the interval time

```
$key = key($_SESSION['Qtime']);
    $start_time = $_SESSION['Qtime'][$key];
        // Do other form processing here..

    $end_time = $_POST['end_time'];

    echo $end_time - $start_time;
```

The echo is negative.

### Ideas Why

I have two ideas why, both of which seem to be wrong:

1. Maybe I'm subtracting the start time of this question with the end
   time of the previous question. It makes sense because I'm storing
   the page load time of the current question in the session, and then
   subtracting it from the submit time in the form.

   In that case, this must be page load time I'm getting. Page load
   time of the current question minus page submit time of the previous
   question -- only the page refresh occurs in that interval.

   But I know I'm wrong because when I hit the submit button, the
   magnitude of the answer is dependent on how long I take to click
   submit. So if I take my time, the answer can go in the negative
   thousands, whereas if I click as quickly as possible, it just stays
   in the negative one hundreds to two hundreds.

   It can't be page refresh time.
2. So idea 2 is that this may be the actual value I want, which is page
   submit minus page load. But then, why is it negative? The negative
   sign seems to tell me I'm getting something in reverse... but I have
   no ideas.

What's happening in this script?

Comment: You set the start time on each load.  You set the end time on each page being sent.  Since the page is sent before the form is submitted, the end time (per your definition) will always be before the start time.

Comment: I don't follow. Wouldn't that give me page refresh time (time between when the page is sent and loaded)? But when I run the script, it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: "My impression is that this is supposed to give me the time when the form is submitted, right? Which means it measures the page submit time. But when I get the difference:" o_O ! What ?! Noooooo, this is not the time when the form is submitted, this is the time when the form is displayed ! PHP is a server side script !!! Your needs is simple: Create a UUID, on page load associate a start time, when form is submitted compare with current time. And you got it !

Comment: Loenix, that's what I'm trying to do. But I don't know how to get the form submit time (I thought I was getting it by using the hidden form already).

Comment: If the start time is `$_SESSION['Qtime'][$form_uuid]` why isn't the end time just `round(microtime(true) * 1000)`?  One is stored in the session (the first) and the other at the time data is being processed (the second)? I have no idea why you would need UUID's for this in terms of time mathematics.

Comment: I've just tried that approach but it gives me weird results. It seems to give me the processing time of the script or something. It always gives me around 10-20 microseconds regardless of how long I take to press.

Comment: I just did `$end_time = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

 echo '<h1>', $end_time - $start_time, '</h1>';`